# button controls in user controls in ListView control as UpdatePanel Triggers in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Here is my scenario..

- I have a ListView Control In my ASP.NET Page.
- The listview is bound to a datasource.
- Then Itemtemplate of ListView makes use of user controls which
  include buttons.
- The ListView is nested in an UpdatePanel.
- I want to set the trigger for the updatepanel to be buttons of UC.

I have come across numerous answers but can't establish a viable solution.

Markup Of UC

```
<div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">        
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateAns" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdateAns_Click">Update</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete the answer?')" CausesValidation="False">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
```

Markup OF UC Container

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="AnswerList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS_Question">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <itstar:AnswerControl runat="server" ID="ansBox" propAnswerID='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' propQuestionID='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>

</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Add aspx markup that will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Button is inside ListView then You Could set the Asycronous post for updatepanel on Button Click on ListView RowDataBound

```
protected void AnswerList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) {
  LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("btnUpdateAns") as LinkButton;
  toolscriptmanagerID.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);  // ToolkitScriptManager
}
```

If you need Full Post Back you could RegisterPostBack for the control.May this [link](https://rojalinsahoo.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/full-page-postback-with-gridview-itemtemplate-control-inside-updatepanel/) will help you out in that case.

Comment: I have used your code in listview itemDataBound Event. Seems like the FindControl function always return **null**.

Comment: is your BtnUpdateAns is inside ListView AnswerList?

Comment: Yes. It is in ListView > User Control > btnUpdateAns. Since the ListView is bound to DataSource. There will be many UCs on the Page

Comment: Could you please update  markup code  for your update panel and listview with btnUpdateAns ?

Comment: After a bit tweaking, I found out that I have to use `LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("ansBox").FindControl("btnUpdateAns") as LinkButton;` so that it will query the correct button. The update problem now solved.  But it will **not** work for the Delete button. When an item is deleted, the data is actually deleted. But it still remains in the page.

Comment: You could use Full Post Back for Delete Button.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the datasource make use of ViewState["para_name"] as its Select Command Parameter. Guess it might be the problem this time.